# Using a GraphQL query to tell React which GraphQL mutation to call next?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a GraphQL endpoint that returns a collection of notifications for a user to see. However, some of those notifications require the user to make a call to a specific mutation, if they choose (for example, the notification displays a button to ask the user to confirm some account details, but the user can choose not to click the button. If they do click it, it needs to hit the correct GraphQL mutation to confirm those details).

Instead of React having a way to know exactly which mutation to call to every notification, I want to just send it back with the notification. For example, something like this for the notification:

```
query {
  users: {
    notifications: {
      title: "Please reconfirm your security account details",
      buttonText: "Click here to reconfirm",
      mutation: {
        name: "reconfirmSecurityAccountDetails",
        argKey: "detail1",
        argValue: "exampleValue"
     }
    }
  }
}
```

So then React will display this notification, and when the user clicks the "Click here to reconfirm", React will know to hit the "reconfirmSecurityAccountDetails" mutation with the args `details1: "exampleDetail"`. Does this seem like okay practice? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

OK for what? security? Not, it's worth almost nothing ... it can only confirm time[-stamp]/sequence of mutations ... it can be processed automatically

For real confirmation you need a scenario similar to recovering password - answer to predefined/choosen ealier question, choose the same value (f.e. picture) to selected earlier, enter value sent by email/sms etc.